# HTTPS and Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am receiving the following stack trace when sending an https request through the load balanced RestTemplate:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://securityService/oauth/token": Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa4e9ed0.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.captureUrlTemplate(RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dfb025c8.postForEntity()
    at com.acme.SecurityService.getBearerToken(SupportServiceImpl.java:62)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:78)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1$1.apply(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1$1.apply(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:98)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:276)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceRestTemplateInterceptor.response(TraceRestTemplateInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.TraceRestTemplateInterceptor.intercept(TraceRestTemplateInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:619)
    ... 50 more
```

How can I configure Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner to enable my Spring Cloud stubs to be accessed via HTTPS?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to do what's documented on [the Wiremock site](http://wiremock.org/docs/https/) with Spring Cloud Contract Sub Runner configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example of how to set up Spring Cloud Contract Wiremock with SSL - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/master/samples/wiremock-undertow-ssl/src/main/resources/application.properties . You can use a similar setup for the normal Wiremocks. Also since you're using Spring Cloud remember about mapping the artifact id to the service name https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.0.x/spring-cloud-contract.html#_stub_runner_spring_cloud